# C# MVC filtering a table via a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which has a table that displays values.  I would like to add a drop down that filters the results of the status column.  So for example if I select "Reviewing", only records with the "Reviewing" status will appear.  Below I have my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<DRT.Models.Master>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestType.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reviewer.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectLocation)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Requestor)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateReceived)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReviewCompDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectFolerLink)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModellingReferralDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModellingReviewCompletionDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SewerMaintenanceReferralDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SewerMaintenanceReviewCompletionDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FlowControlReferralDate)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestType.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reviewer.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectLocation)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Requestor)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateReceived)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewCompDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectFolerLink)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectComments)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DischargeLocationID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DischargeDistrict)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AffectedRequlator)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDateOfDischarge)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DurationOfDischarge)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestFlowRate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApprovedDischargeRate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DischargeLocationComments)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModellingReferralDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModellingReviewCompletionDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SewerMaintenanceReferralDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SewerMaintenanceReviewCompletionDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlowControlReferralDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MasterId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MasterId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MasterId })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: I am not sure where to begin.  I have very little experience using MVC besides generating the default Views and controllers. Most of the filtering I have found was via a search box that would filter the results.

Comment: See the section in this link "Filter using DropDownList" http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/filter-records-in-mvc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need a SELECT element in your view and when use selects something, you may post the selected value to the action method where you will use this value when getting data from your db.

You may create a new view model

```
public class ListAndSearchVm
{
  public IEnumerable<DRT.Models.Master> Data { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { set;get;}
  public string SelectedStatus { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, you need to load the `Statuses` property of the view model and the `Data` property. Have a parameter to accept the selected option value from your status filter dropdown. Based on the value of this parameter get the filtered data.

```
public ActionResult Index(string selectedStatus="")
{
  var vm= new ListAndSearchVm();

  //Hard coding 2 items for demo. You can read this from your db table
  vm.Statuses = new List<SelectListItem> {
     new SelectListITem { Value="Open", Text="Open"},
     new SelectListITem { Value="Closed", Text="Closed"},
  };

  var data= dbContext.Masters;
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedStatus))
  {
     data = data.Where(f=>f.Status.Name==selectedSatatus);
  }      
  vm.Data = data.ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view

```
@model ListAndSerchVm
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","YourControllerName",FormMethod.Get))
{
  <label> Select a status</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(f=>f.SelectedStatus,Model.Statuses,"Select")
  <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Request type</th>
    <th>Reviewer</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>
@foreach(var item in Model.Data)
{
  <tr>
       <td>@item.RequestType.Name)</td>
       <td>@item.Reviewer.Name</td>
       <td>@item.Status.Name</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: So would the first part of the code go into a new view and the second part would go into where?

Comment: It is all in the same view (Index.cshtml)

Comment: So all three go into the same view?

Comment: What is three ? If you meant the code in answer, The first part goes in a class ,second in your controller action method and the third for your razor view for that action method.

Comment: When I did this I received two error, one in the Class stating "The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found."  The second is in the view, "Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file."

Comment: `SelectListItem` belongs to `System.Web.Mvc` namespace. So make sure you have a `using System.Web.Mvc;` in your file. Also in my answer, I never used 2 model declaration. So i am guessing you are doing something different than the answer i posted. In short, the model of the view should be `ListAndSearchVm` type.

Comment: My view is already using "@model IEnumerable<DRT.Models.Master>" which i believe is required for the table to display the values.  Am I wrong?  You should be able to see this in the code I posted in my original question.

Comment: Please read the answer from start to end. We created a new view model for your view. so you should make your view strongly typed to that. To render the table, instead of using `Model`, you will use `Model.Data` as your new view mode has a `Data` property which is same as your old model(`IEnumerable<DRT.Models.Master>`)