# Add a filter to a table column

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, model-view-controller

What would be the easiest way to add a filter to a table column(Status)?  I found different things but they all suggest something like a search box but I do not want that.  I tried another thing but it has not been working. Below is my code without any filters.  I highly appreciate your help.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult ViewAllTasks()
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle dbhandle = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            return View(dbhandle.GetITTasksList());
        }

        //LIST IT TASKS
        public JsonResult ListITTasks()
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            return Json(hdDB.GetITTasksList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
@*IT TASKS PAGE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*@

@model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSupport.Models.ITTasksModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ViewAllTasks</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/ITTasksJS.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <h2>IT Tasks</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
                  onclick="clearTextBox();">Add New Task</button><br /><br />

    <table class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="knowledgeTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITDescription)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEnterDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITAssignedTo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEstimatedCompletion)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITPriority)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITFrom)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITStatus)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="tbody">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITDescription)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEnterDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITAssignedTo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEstimatedCompletion)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITPriority)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITFrom)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITStatus)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//Load Data in Table when documents is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadData();
});

//Load Data function
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/ListITTasks",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITNumber + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITDescription + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEnterDate + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITAssignedTo + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEstimatedCompletion + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITPriority + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITFrom + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITStatus + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyTicketNumber(' + item.ITNumber + 
               ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="DeleteItTask(' + item.ITNumber + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
            alert("Successful Loaddata ITTASK");
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

THANKS A LOT AGAIN!!!

Comment: What are the possible values of `ITStatus`?

Comment: Closed or open would be the values of status.

Answer (score 0):

Add your request url Status Value like :

```
url: "/Tickets/ListITTasks?status=0",
```

I assume that Status prop accept int. You can change to string.

Then add your controller function parameter like :

```
public JsonResult ListITTasks(int status){}
```

Then in your Repository create new(or update `GetITTasksList()`) function with accepting int parameter. And write your sql or linq filter with PredicateBuilder or .Where().
Then return result of course.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about your answer.  I am new to MVC.  Also, I want to display all data in the table and then filter it only when they decide to.  I would like a filter on top of the column.

Comment: If you need filter from API this answer will be helpful for you, but you need filter from front page then you will use some Js methods. First of all you need to decide that.

Comment: If you need Js methods: I am not sure but; declare a variable for user's status choice then in your <tbody> @foreach(var item in Model.filter(x=> x.ITStatus == statusChoice)). This gives you your filtered dataSet.

Comment: Do you have some example code for the controller, view and javascript? I tried what is in this link but it is not working...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495363/c-sharp-mvc-filtering-a-table-via-a-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I ended up using Datatables which also have a filter functionality